# Array Insert in Form

Tags: php, arrays, jquery

Only editor can post into database but the price could'nt Post into database..

So, how can i make query let say 1st Row in form has Field 1 = Fullname, Field 2 = Age.. and i can add new row again with the same field and submit all information to array into database

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include "_config/config.php";
    //include "header.php";


    if (isset($_POST["editor"])) //&& ($_POST["price"]) && is_array($_POST["price"]) && count($_POST["price"]) > 0) 
    { 
    foreach($_POST["editor"] as $editor)
       { 
           // echo htmlspecialchars($editor, ENT_QUOTES); 
           mysql_connect($server, $db_user, $db_pass)  or die ("Database CONNECT Error (line 62)"); 
           mysql_db_query($database, "INSERT INTO arrayins VALUES   ('','$editor','$price')");

       echo "Data Successfully Added";
            echo '<br />'; 
        } 
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Many things about this.. First, where do you set `$price`? not in the code shown...  Next, establish your database connection once per script, not on each iteration of a loop, since you are not even closing connections you have opened.  Finally, this is highly vulnerable to SQL injection, as you are performing no escaping on `$_POST['editor']`.

Comment: @Michael custom: no, deprecated: yes, TFM: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-db-query.php

Comment: @TheNail Oh I forgot all about that function.

Comment: The '(line 62)' in the DB connect error is wrong, it should be 'line 12' ;-)

Comment: @PhpDeveloper `mysql_db_query()` was deprecated long ago.

Comment: there is no error in DB connection... This script is half of my Php scripts... only i want to how can i insert into database if 1st row field is same as second row....

Comment: @PhpDeveloper I didn't say there's an error with your connection, I said you should not be reestablishing it on each iteration of a loop. Since you aren't closing it in between, you are piling up unused connections to the database.  That's merely a suggestion. Your _problem_ lies in the fact that `$price` is unset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first determine the number of rows posted, and then loop over the row index and get the appropriate values:

```
$num_rows = is_array($_POST["editor"]) ? count($_POST["editor"]) : 0;

for ($i = 0; $i < $num_rows; $i++) {
    $editor = $_POST["editor"][$i];
    $price = $_POST["price"][$i];

    // your SQL code here using $editor and $price
}
```